# Laravel: Helpers class not found on live site. Works locally

Tags: php, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to use the thujohn/twitter package to get a live twitter feed on my site.

I got it working on my local server by using the tutorial found [here](http://www.mackhankins.com/blog/laravel/simple-twitter-feed-with-caching-using-laravel-and-twitter-api) but when I uploaded the changes to my digital Ocean server, I got the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Helpers' not found
```

Here are the steps I took - not much code:

- I downloaded the package with artisan
- config/app.php: added `'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider'`, to the providers and `'Twitter' => 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade'`  to the aliases
- added `app_path().'/classes'`, to the `start/global.php` file
- I added a Helpers class to classes/helpers.php, which contains:

```
public static function twitterFeed($screen_name='screenName', $count='1', $include_retweets='false', $exclude_replies='true')
{    
    $twitterfeed = Cache::remember('twitterfeed', 30, function() use ($screen_name, $count, $include_retweets, $exclude_replies) {
        return Twitter::getUserTimeline(
            array(
                'screen_name' => $screen_name, 
                'count' => $count, 
                'include_rts' => $include_retweets, 
                'exclude_replies' => $exclude_replies
            )
        );
    })
    ;
    if(!empty($twitterfeed)) {
        return $twitterfeed;
    }
    else {
        return array();
    }        
}
```

- Put a view::share in my route file:

  ```
  View::share('tweets', Helpers::twitterFeed('contractrsherpa', '1', false, true));
  ```
- then looped through it in my view.
- Finally, ran composer dump-autoload.

Seems pretty straightforward and works great locally. I uploaded everything to my liver server, ran composer dump-autoload, but still get the error  "class 'Helpers' not found."

Any idea what I need to do to get this to work on the live site?

TIA

Comment: You mention you downloaded the package with artisan -- did you mean composer? Packages are usually installed via Composer, either by updating the composer.json file, or by running 

    composer require my/package

Comment: @mike.bronner my mistake - I downloaded it by running php artisan config:publish thujohn/twitter